# c# Image and text on a button, centered in the button?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, button, text

I have a button on a C# Windows Form form, and want to show an image and some text, side by side, and centered on the button. I tried aligning the image to the left and the text to the right, and I'm getting this (the periods are spaces):

> |[IMAGE}.................Text|

But I want this:

> |........[IMAGE] Text........|

My code looks like this:

```
btnChangeStatus.Text = "Change status to SUPPRESSED";
btnChangeStatus.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;

btnChangeStatus.Image=Image.FromFile(@"J:\nomail.gif");
btnChangeStatus.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

I've searched here, and found lots of stuff for Java or HTML, but nothing for C#. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this winforms, ASP.NET, WPF, or what? Please clarify that point, and show the code you have.

Comment: Edited with that info. Thanks.

Comment: So is it winforms? Please tag questions appropriately. People who habitually answer winforms questions will watch the winforms tag. If your question isn't tagged as winforms, some of them will never see it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I haven't posted much, so I'm still familiarizing myself with the protocol. Yes, it's Winforms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [`TextImageRelation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.textimagerelation) to [`TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textimagerelation):

```
btnChangeStatus.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
btnChangeStatus.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;        
btnChangeStatus.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

> Specifies that the image is displayed horizontally before the text of a control.

---

UPDATE: You are right, though it sounds like this should do what you want, it's still a little to the left.
I tried around a little and using

```
btnChangeStatus.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
btnChangeStatus.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight; // <- right here
btnChangeStatus.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```

leads to the desired result, but I can't tell why the button behaves like that.

Comment: That's got me a lot closer, but the image/text is still a bit off-center to the left.

Comment: @John you are right, updated my answer with what works for me, though I unfortunately don't know the reason for this strange behaviour