# How to add an image icon before the text of a WinForms button?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, ico, iconbutton

I'm trying to add .ico 48x48 image before text in WinForms button 87x30 size:

```
  button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;  
  button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.None;                 
  button1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom;  
  button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
  button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
  button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
```

Result is:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out, how to align image on the left side with text on related distance, like this:

[image]

**edit:**

```
    button1.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
    button1.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft; /// MiddleRight; // MiddleCenter; 
    button1.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight; /// MiddleLeft;
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like  you are mixing Image and BackgroundImage?

Comment: You should set `Image` property to an image, then both `ImageAlign` and `TextAlign` should be set to `MiddleLeft`, and `TextImageRelation` should be `ImageBeforeText`.

Comment: I wonder what _Image before the text_ is supposed to mean: z.order or horizontal placement..

Comment: It's horizontal/vertical alignment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# Image and text on a button, centered in the button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368199/c-sharp-image-and-text-on-a-button-centered-in-the-button)

Comment: Without using  BackgroundImageLayout image is duplicated

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Please check edit

Comment: @Olivier Rogier  I got same result as show in my first results

Comment: @iose936 You need to assign `Image` property and clear `BackGroundImage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image property is like the operating system desktop background, it is a wallpaper, that can be stretched, adapted, repeated...

Therefore here you don't need to use `BackgroundImage` for a button icon style image associated to its text.

If you use the `Image` property and set alignments to left for it and right for text, all works fine:

[image]

[image]

Then you can adapt these alignments as well as width and height to the desired result depending on the image size and/or text size and length.

---

Also, as indicated by the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46368199/c-sharp-image-and-text-on-a-button-centered-in-the-button) I finally found, to simply center all, you can use the `TextImageRelation` and set it to `TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText` without changing alignments, and if necessary by increasing the height according to the size of the displayed image to have a clean result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, if I get it correct, I've added result in edit, please check

Comment: You need to remove the background image, and use only the `Image` property. Click on the `...` right to the `BackgroundImage` in the Property Visual Editor and click on `Erase/Remove` in the `Local Resource` section. Remove the button and drop a new one to reset the properties if something goes wrong.

Comment: Sorry I've missed that point, correct. But then I have to resize image